# How to convert text file asset into List<String>

Tags: flutter

May I ask, How do i read a plaintext, located at `assets/plaintext.txt`, with the following content

```
1st line
2nd line
3rd line
```

and convert it into something, which act like, the following would have

```
List<String> stri = <String>[
"1st line",
"2nd line",
"3rd line",
];
```

The following code makes the app screen go black

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

String stri = '0';
Future<void> main() async {
  stri = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/plaintext.txt');
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}
```

Thanking you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a string first using rootBundle.loadString() method, and then construct a list out of a pattern.

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

void loadAsset() async {
  String loadedString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/plaintext.txt');
  List<String> result = loadedString.split('\n');
}
```

Don't forget to add it in your pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/plaintext.txt
```

Comment: Is there any way, that converts to List <Complext> ?